# Ubuntu OpenStack Installation requirement - single disk and seven machines?

Tags: server, disk, openstack

I just started configuring Openstack with Ubuntu as per [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

Installing Ubuntu OpenStack requires at least seven machines with two disks, two of which have two network interfaces (NICs). Install Ubuntu Server on one of the machines with two interfaces.

My Question: Can I **install** Ubuntu Openstack **with single disk** on all **seven** machines?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to select the Multi Install path in order to place your services on your existing seven machines. It should work fine with single disks on each machine.

This link should get you started with the installer, juju, and maas.

http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multi-installer.guide.html